# Enabling Pop-up view/Split Screen View

Tags: android, split-screen

When trying to view my android app in split screen view I get the message:

`The current screen does not support split screen view.`

The same for when I want to open it in pop-up view I get the message:

`Cannot open app in pop-up view`

How can I enable split screen view for my app?

Comment: What is "split screen view"? What is "pop-up view"?

Comment: @CommonsWare for an example see http://hexus.net/media/uploaded/2012/10/6e057e73-55fe-4b7c-bb4f-203b9e2de483.jpg

Comment: Are you referring to Samsung's multi-window stuff? If so,  try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111052/adding-multi-window-support-to-android-application and `samsung multi window sdk` on your favorite search engine.